# Visual Studio 2010 goes very slow during and after "Find in Files" search option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Can anybody help me on this. I have been working on the same machine for last six months with Visual Studio 2010 as my development tool with no issue.

However for last few days I have been facing trouble when I search any word using "Find in Files" option in **Entire Solution** or In **Current Project**. At first place it does take normal time in searching, but  as soon as it finished the search, my visual studio IDE goes dead slow, and subsequently it takes a 2, 3 seconds for even cursor up and down on the editor.

Before search the CPU Usage is in Task Manager is as normal as 2 - 5 percent but after search it start using CPU at 25 to 30 percent and VS 2010 goes dead slow.

Surprisingly if I leave VS 2010 idle for around 20-30 minutes it comes to normal response and CPU USAGE on task manager again shows normal usage like 2-5 percent and everything is fine.

As a work around I did the following
 1- Deleted all temp files
 2- Deleted all ASP.Net Temporary Files
 3- Cleared all TFS Cache.
 4- Even uninstalled and re-installed complete VS 2010

None of the above worked.

Comment: not sure if this will solve your exact issues, but, i resolved some VS2010 responsiveness issue by deleting the .suo file in the solution root directory

Comment: Thank yakyb... sorry for replying late since i was too much busy with my project.  your suggestion worked and made my life easier.. thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this issue by deleting the the solution file name with .suo extension as suggested by Yak

Comment: When someone answers you in the comments section, it's nice if you ask them to write it as answer so you can actually mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Areks. I will take care of this next time :)

Comment: @Areks (s)he can't actually, since it is not an answer but a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I vaguely recall a similar experience some years ago. I cannot say for sure if it the same problem that you are experiencing, but I believe I managed to get out of the misery by clearing the search dialog/panels. It seemed like it kept repeating the search even when the panel was not displayed.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You might want to include some steps for clearing the search/dialog panels.

Comment: @valverij that is a good idea. Unfortunately I do not recall the exact steps I did to recover form this issue and I cannot reproduce the error and do not have VS2010 anymore. My best advice would be to activate the various search panels and to experiment with clearing all the fields in the different search dialogs...